# Why one weak reference gets deallocated and other doesn't?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, weak-references

I am getting used to using **weak** and **strong** references and when to use them and when not and I got to a case like described below (check the comment about the warning)

```
@interface MPIViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIView *subview;
@property (weak, nonatomic) UILabel *label;
@end

@implementation MPIViewController
// ...
// some code here
// ...  

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.subview = [[UIView alloc] init];   // warning here: assigning retained object to weak property 
    self.label = [[UILabel alloc] init];    // no warnings

    [self.view addSubView: self.subview];
    [self.view addSubView: self.label]; 
}

// ...
// some code here
// ...  
@end
```

From description of **`- (void)addSubview:(UIView *)view`**:

> This method establishes a strong reference to view and sets its next
>   responder to the receiver, which is its new superview.

This means that this object won't be `deallocated` after method finishes as it's `superview` will retain it and hold a strong reference to it and therefore this view will be kept in memory for as long as its superview is there. Am I right here?

I am not sure also if I understand assigning here correctly. Warning says that it will be `deallocated` straight after the assignment but this sounds wrong as then it wouldn't be possible to assign any variable to a weak pointer as it would get `deallocated` in the next line of code?

For `UILabel` same assign works fine, however for `UIView` it doesn't? Does the compiler treat UIView somehow differently? This really puzzles me how that is even possible.

This code can be fixed easily just by assigning the UIView to a local method variable and then passing it to the setter like this:

```
UIView *tmpView = [[UIView alloc] init];
self.subview = tmpView;
```

Variables declared in the method are by default **`strong`** so having such a construction removes the warning as the compiler thinks that this variable has a strong reference so weak reference that is then assigned to will be kept as long as the method variable will point to it. BUT! how does that make sense as the tmpView is only a local method variable and will be dumped after method will finish?

Comment: if you comment the code where you take the warning you'll see that the warning come to the second alloc as well

Comment: Someone needs a strong reference to the views. If they are not IBOutlets then the strong pointer is generally held by the controller. In this situation your views should be `strong`.

Comment: He wants to add the views to a view as subview. Views hold their subviews. *They* should hold the views. This is, why he is asking. Furthermore there is a warning in one case and no one in another case.

Comment: @Maciej Pigulski Is there a typo in your code? Shouldn't it be […addSubview:*self.*subview]?

Comment: @Amin Negm-Awad, yes, it is a typo, I have fixed it now. Also you are right about the other stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the first question:

Let's have a closer look to it:

```
self.subview = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

`[UIView alloc]` returns an instance with ownership +1. This is assigned to a (non-visible) strong reference, which build the `self` of `-init`. `-init` passes the ownership through. (This is not correct, if `-init` returns an instance which is not the original receiver, but for your case it is enough details.) So we can think of the return value of `-init` as an ownership transfer, too.

You assign this instance to a weak variable. In this moment it *can* be released. (Read: ARC does not promise to do it immediately, IIRC.) the instance variable can be `nil` before the object is hold by its superview. So this code is dangerous:

```
self.subview = [[UIView alloc] init];
// _subview can be nil'ed
[self.view addSubView: self.subview]; // add nil
```

I do not believe that this is your problem, but it can be a problem. – Thinking again about it, it *is* your problem. Read the edit at the end. –To get rid of it, simply use a strong local variable:

```
UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] init]; // defaults to __strong
[self.view addSubView: subview]; // adds an ownership
self.subview = subview;
```

The second question:

I do not know, why the compiler gives you no warning in the second case. What does happen, if you repair the first case?

At runtime a different handling of both cases is possible, because it is undefined, when the first instance is released. Maybe as a part of optimization a pointer is reused. More detailed:

```
__strong id completlyHiddenCompilerGeneratedVar;
… = [(completlyHiddenCompilerGeneratedVar=[UIView alloc]) init];
… = [(completlyHiddenCompilerGeneratedVar=[UILabel alloc]) init];
```

The first instance would be dealloc'ed, when the second instance is created, because it overwrites the internal strong reference.

Again: Repair the first case and tell us, what happens with the second one.

Comment: The fact that ARC can release immediately a 'weak' reference is done like that by design? What purpose does it server exactly? Because maybe I am just missing a concept with this and thats why I run into confusion. That is language over here allows me to assign a variable to a weak property but it is something I shouldn't be doing (however it works in some cases, I'll get to that in the last part of this comment).

Comment: I have done a workaround with a local variable that is by default strong (it is mentioned in the question, that I know that this can be fixed this way, there is also another question about that bit that is also confusing - see the very last paragraph of the question).

Comment: As to the point that I should fix one of the warnings: code that is generating this scenarion is much larger then the example here. Now I have created a sample view controller that wants to reproduce this issue and I am getting two warnings straight away. In the code that this problem originates from (it is not much more complicated, just has a lot more code, but nothing serious) I have fixed the issue with UIView by assigning it to local variable, warning was gone, but no warning appeared for UILabel.

Comment: As mentioned the handling in this case is hidden and you cannot rely on this in no way. But I would like to have a warning in both cases, yes.

Comment: To your first comment: It is the concept of reference counting: If you have no strong reference to an object, it can (really: can!) be released. AFAIK there is no promise, that this will happen immediately. There is no need for it, because you do something "wrong". For C it is typical in such cases to simply say "undefined". Maybe you would get additional messages, when turning zombies on. BTW: The language allows to divide by 0. You shouldn't do that. ;-) It is impossible for a compiler to find all problems in your code.

Comment: To your second comment and the last paragraph of your question: Probably you have the misunderstanding, that strong vars are for "long life", weak vars are for "local life". This is not true. You need a strong var locally to hold the object locally.

Answer (score 0):

An object need at least one strong pointer to it in order to be kept in memory.

So when you alloc it to a weak pointer that condition is not being met. Make your properties `strong` if you really need to access these views.

Comment: @occulus Untrue. Not with ARC. +alloc is ownership transferring. It loses it's ownership and therefore the returned object has to be kept by a strong pointer. Without that you will lose the object immediately.

Comment: Whoops, my brain is in completely backwards this morning. Sorry all, thought we were dealing with manual memory management.